# Excel : Horizontal axis label changed when making a chart

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I was making a chart (stacked column) based on data in excel in which the horizontal axis labels relate to this row :

```
1-Feb  2-Feb  3-Feb  6-Feb  7-Feb  8-Feb
```

However, in the chart, all has changed to : d-Feb.

I tried all the options but I cannot change it back.

If you had a solution using VBA it would be great too.

The stacked column chart is like this but bigger :

For the y axis, stats are :

```
647  810    1001 719  
300  720    420  360  
330  210    390  250  
0     60     60  108  
270  240    270  300  
0     60      0   60  
285  270    180  270  
510  460    375  330
```

For the x axis, labels are (no weekend days) :

```
1-Feb   2-Feb   3-Feb   6-Feb
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please read [ask] first. Then please understand that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. If you have specific questions to code you wrote then you are welcome to show your code so we can help you with it.

Comment: You intend to skip the 4th and 5th of Feb. right? Also does it literally return `d-Feb` or ...what?  It may help to see some of the data as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. It was kind of an emergncy. I modified the question. Unfortunately, I don't have any code to begin with since one line of code might already solve the problem.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, it literally returns d-Feb while I want it to show 1-Feb...

Comment: @FrancisZHENG hmm. Can you post some sample data showing how it's laid out? Also is the text in the row formatted as a date or general or what?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, I put it in the question. The 1-Feb... are formatted as date type.

Comment: Hm, I tried using your data, and was able to get the correct dates to show. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQTWU.jpg).  Can you post a screenshot of your chart and the data?

Comment: I can't see your screenshot or put up mine because of the internet restriction at work...

Comment: I found the solution. In the chart axis option, choose date as format, then enter *jj/mmm and click add. It has to have *, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In the chart axis option, choose date as format, then enter *jj/mmm and click add. It has to have *, otherwise it wouldn't work.